# Created Windows Form needs the Textbox to have the cursor and return hits button

Tags: c#

I have a little form that I created to ask the user of my C# program to enter some text.  When the program gets to a point in the program the form pops up with a label in the form that says something like “Enter the number” and a Textbox that allows them to type it in. There is a Button so they can hit OK and have the form close and send back the value in the Textbox.   I have 2 problems

First, when the form comes up I want the cursor to be in the Textbox so people can just start typing.  Right now they have to click in the Textbox. I thought that having the focus be on the textbox would cause that but as you can see below, I tried that.

Second, when someone is in the Textbox typing and they hit return I want it to be as if the Button that I have on the form is hit.  The form would do all the things that would be done like end and send the Text back, as if someone had hit the OK.

I have Windows XP and Visual Studio 2008.

This is the code that I have:

```
    public static class Prompt
    {
        public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
        {
            Form prompt = new Form();
            prompt.Width = 600;
            prompt.Height = 200;
            prompt.Text = caption;

            Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Width = 600, Text = text };

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };


            textBox.Focus();

            Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70 };

            confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };


            prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);

            prompt.ShowDialog();
            return textBox.Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the focus on your control, just set a Load event on your new form and use  .Select()

```
            prompt.Load += delegate { textBox.Select(); };
```

For the button, use the form AcceptButton property

```
            prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;
```

Those two lines of code should give you the result you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Calling   `textBox.Focus();` before the `ShowDialog()` has no effect. You would have to call this from the Form's FormLoad event.

But there is an easier way, just add the TextBox first:

```
   //prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
   //prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
   //prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);

   prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
   prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
   prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
```

Comment: I think the actual effect is that it will set focus but then the dialog requests focus when its shown

Comment: Sayse, a Form will always forward Focus to it's first control. And the OP calls it even before the TextBox has a parent (or a Handle).

Comment: Ah ok cheers, I knew it "stole" focus, just didn't know where it took it

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `ActiveControl` property of the form to the textbox to get it to focus

   `prompt.ActiveControl = textbox`
2. Set the forms's `AcceptButton` to the button you want pressed:

   `prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation`

Answer (score 1):

1. `textbox.Focus()` will give focus to the textbox, As henk said this should be done in the load form event... I had assumed you were creating the textbox dynamically

   `prompt.Shown += (sender, e) => { textBox.Focus(); };`
2. this

   ```
       textBox.KeyUp += (sender, e) =>
       {
           if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("enter pressed");
           }
       };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, simply go to your form designer, choose `Tab Order` from `View` menu and make sure your TextBox has Tab Order set to ZERO.

For the second problem, set your OK button's `DialogResult` to `OK` and set your form's `AcceptButton` property to the name of your OK button.